# How to reformat a string of sentences to be one sentence per line Python

Tags: python, string, split, n-gram, sentence

I have a file that is just one big string. In this string there are sentences that end with 3 numbers like so:

> sees mouse . 1980 1 1 sheep erythrocytes mouse 1980 6 5 seen mouse 1980 8 8

I want to change this so that the file/output looks like this:

> sees mouse . 1980 1 1
>
> sheep erythrocytes mouse 1980 6 5
>
> seen mouse 1980 8 8

Here is the code I have been using to try and solve this problem:

```
with open('ngram_test') as f:
for line in f:
    #print(line)
    for word in line.split():
        print(word)
```

This, however, only prints each word in the string and a newline. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Will numbers ever occur in the sentences? Or are the only numbers the 3 after each sentence?

Comment: Numbers do not occur in the sentences themselves, the only numbers are the 3 after each sentence yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Regex, you can add newline (`\n`) after each pattern occurrence:

```
import re
s = "sees mouse . 1980 1 1 sheep erythrocytes mouse 1980 6 5 seen mouse 1980 8 8"
pattern = r"(\d{4}\s\d{1,2}\s\d{1,2})"
for match in re.findall(pattern, s):
    s = re.sub(match, f'{match}\n', s)
```

**Output:**

```
'sees mouse . 1980 1 1\n sheep erythrocytes mouse 1980 6 5\n seen mouse 1980 8 8\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `regexp` and find indexes of required string and strip them later.

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z\.\s]+\d{4}\s+?\d{1,2}\s+?\d{1,2}')
print([(m.start(0), m.end(0)) for m in re.finditer(pattern, s)])
```

This will work assuming that input is limited by strings provided into the question. If no, you would need to extend pattern.

Answer (score 0):

A simplex regex should do

```
a='sees mouse . 1980 1 1 sheep erythrocytes mouse 1980 6 5 seen mouse 1980 8 8'
count=0
for i in re.finditer('(\d \d \d)',a):
    print(a[count:i.end()].strip())
    count=i.end()
```

Comment: `\d*` to pick up the numbers with multiple digits.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is looking for 3 numbers sequence.
Note that this a beginner level solution and does not involve regex.

```
def is_int(value):
    try:
        int(value)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False


with open('54928944.txt', 'r') as f:
    numbers_counter = 0
    one_line_words = []
    line = f.read()
    words = line.split(' ')
    for word in words:
        if is_int(word):
            numbers_counter += 1
        else:
            numbers_counter = 0
        one_line_words.append(word)
        if numbers_counter == 3:
            print(' '.join(one_line_words))
            one_line_words = []
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```py
import re  
print(re.sub(r'(\d{4} \d{1,2} \d{1,2} )', r'\1\n', 'sees
mouse . 1980 1 1 sheep erythrocytes mouse 1980 6 5 seen mouse 1980 8
8'))
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the results in a list, you can use re.split().

From `re`built-in lib.

```py
>>> import re

>>> with open(ngram_test) as f:
...    s = f.read()

>>> splitted = re.split(r"r"\d*\s\d\s\d"", s)

>>> splitted
>>> ['sees mouse . ', ' sheep erythrocytes mouse ', ' seen mouse ', '']
```